# angularjs - implement route's resolve feature without routing/ng-view

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, resolve

In a big application, i now need to access some data (json api call) from  asynchronously (before, those data were accessed synchronously). 
I would like not to have to change components implementation to now handle this async behaviour (too risky).

I thought about $routeProvider's "resolve" feature (with promises) that helps to abstract this async behaviour out from the components/controllers.

Unfortunately i am absolutely not using routing in any way.

Is there an implementation for that? If not, where could i start?

**EDIT:**

how i was before (jsonData were not loaded synchronously but it was transparent thanks to systemJS features, SystemJS, Which we are throwing in garbage now, hence the question):
https://plnkr.co/edit/BSreVYNAr7sijYwEpb5G?p=preview

How i am now: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/WnX0ynOqkZsmEzIxl1SI?p=preview

Watch the console to see an example of the problems that can occur now.

I kind of made it work by going like that, but i'm not completely satisfied with it (watch the config block):
https://plnkr.co/edit/P9Rv6rnboFlaFZ0OARNG?p=preview

```
$provide.value('$provide', $provide);
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            template: '<test></test>',
            controller: function ($provide, myJsonData1) {
                $provide.value('myJsonData', myJsonData1);
            },
            resolve: {
                myJsonData1: function(){
                  return getMyJsonData();
                }
            } 
        });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is it possible to see your minimal setup, that will illustrate the architecture of your  app?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash question updated

Comment: Most of the .config callback appears to be repetitive boilerplate, with only the template and asyncData getter varying from config to config. If so, and if your concern is code bulk, then you can write eg `function apply(options) { return ($routeProvider, $provide) => {/* bulky code here */}; }`, and compose your .configs with much less bulky `.config([ "$routeProvider", "$provide", apply({ template: '<test></test>', getter: getMyJsonData })]).run(function ($route) { });`.

Comment: If you discover a better approach then, with luck, you need only change `apply()`.